# Using Bulk API on iOS, any library or sample project?

Tags: soap, bulk-api, ios

I decide to use bulk api to push all data on my iOS application to salesforce periodically. I have read throw the Bulk API document. It provides some sample code in java using salesforce libraries. I am wondering if salesforce provides similar libraries or sample codes for iOS client application? Or we would do the web calls and xml/csv serialization ourself like doing it in C#?

Comment: You gotta do it like in C# unless you can find a 3rd party library that wraps useful functions up.  We've written our own Java SalesforceConnections library